# How to upload a CSV file and and read it's data in the client side itself and send the data as a stream through a ajax post?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, jquery-plugins, jquery, asp.net-ajax, csv

I need to upload a CSV file and get its contents form the client side itself. Then post it to the server where I can retriev the stream and do the string manipulations in the serer action methods.
Is there any jquery plugin for this task to upload a csv file and send data as a stream using ajax or jason?
I am really new to this area.I am working in VS2010 AND mvc3.

Can some one give me a clear solution for this mater??
Any examples?? I did search a lot but did not find any suitable solution yet.
Can anyone please help me with this matter.
Thanks so much.

Comment: If I use http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload jquery upload plugin, which supports  *Multipart and file contents stream uploads: 
Files can be uploaded as standard "multipart/form-data" or file contents stream (HTTP PUT file upload), how can I send the data stream using ajax or http??I am new to this. A help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your action method you can do something like:

```
public ActionResult ProcessFile(HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile){
Stream stream = uploadedFile.InputStream;

// Do something with the data

}
```